# How to pass "unnecessary" pointers to a function?

Tags: c, pointers

This function is given to me by an API:

```
void GetTime(uint8_t*, uint8_t*, uint8_t*, uint8_t*, uint8_t*, uint8_t* );
```

`GetTime` returns the time by writing to those pointers. Problem is, I only need the value written to one of those pointers. If I could control `GetTime` I'd either check if the pointers were `NULL` or return a struct instead, but I can't.

This is my current solution, ignoring the dummy* pointers:

```
uint8_t *seconds, *dummy0, *dummy1, *dummy3, *dummy4, *dummy5;
GetTime( dummy0, dummy1, dummy3, dummy4, dummy5, seconds );
```

Is there a neater way to solve this problem with less clutter?

Comment: You're passing uninitialized pointers.

Answer (score 7):

First, you are doing it wrong, you need to allocate a uint8_t and pass a pointer to it.

Secondly you can use the same dummy for all:

```
uint8_t seconds, dummy;
GetTime( &dummy,&dummy,&dummy,&dummy,&dummy, &seconds );
```

Finally, the API may accept NULL. Does this work?:

```
uint8_t seconds;
GetTime( NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL, &seconds );
```

Answer (score 2):

As suggested before, you could have a function like this that helps you call `GetTime`

```
uint8_t dummy[5];
uint8_t seconds;

GetTime(dummy, dummy + 1, dummy + 2, dummy + 3, dummy + 4, &seconds);

return seconds;
```

If you know that `GetTime` works properly with pointers that aren't unique, you could just get away with this (but then again, you're only saving 4 bytes):

```
uint8_t dummy, seconds;

GetTime(&dummy, &dummy, &dummy, &dummy, &dummy, &seconds);

return seconds;
```

Comment: If `GetTime()` has trouble with non-unique pointers, should not it be prototyped as `void GetTime(restrict uint8_t*, restrict uint8_t*, etc.)`?  I'm fuzzy on using restrict in destination pointers.  Maybe that's a question to post?

Answer (score 1):

Write a helper function that makes a call to this function providing dummy pointers and only takes a single pointer - the one that you care about.